# Stored variable of Self type (especially when subclassing)

Tags: swift, inheritance, self

```
class LinkedNode<T> {
    var value: T
    var next: Self?
    
    required init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class DoublyNode<T>: LinkedNode<T> {
    weak var previous: DoublyNode?
    override var next: Self? {
        didSet { next.previous = self }
    }
}
```

I wish it compiles like this. But it doesn't.

> Stored property cannot have covariant 'Self' type

I have to rewrite the code to make it compile and work:

```
class LinkedNode<T> {
    var value: T
    var next: LinkedNode?
    
    required init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

class DoublyNode<T>: LinkedNode<T> {
    weak var previous: DoublyNode?
    override var next: LinkedNode<T>? {
        didSet { (next as! Self).previous = self }
    }
}
```

And everywhere in the later code every time after referring to `next` property I have to manually cast it to DoublyNode (when I'm working with DoublyNode) because it always has type LinkedNode.
It's manageable but annoying and ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me demonstrate why Swift disallows this. If it did allow you to use `Self` like that, you could in theory do:

```
let doublyNode = DoublyNode(1)
let linkedNode: LinkedNode<Int> = doublyNode // this assignment should work, right?
linkedNode.next = LinkedNode(2) // "linkedNode" is of type LinkedNode, so Self is LinkedNode, so I can do this assignment, right?
```

Now what happens? The `didSet` of `next` in `DoublyNode` gets called, and it tries to access `previous` of `LinkedNode(2)`. The thing is, `LinkedNode` doesn't even have a `previous` property! Therefore, allowing you to use `Self` this way is unsafe.

I don't think `DoublyNode` should inherit from `LinkedNode` at all. Alexander's answer explains this very well, namely that this violates the [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). One thing you could do to relate these two classes, is with a protocol:

```
protocol LinkedNodeProtocol {
    associatedtype Data
    
    var value: Data { get set }
    var next: Self? { get set }
    
    init(_ value: Data)
}

final class LinkedNode<Data>: LinkedNodeProtocol {
    var value: Data
    var next: LinkedNode?
    
    init(_ value: Data) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

final class DoublyNode<Data>: LinkedNodeProtocol {
    var value: Data
    weak var previous: DoublyNode?
    var next: DoublyNode? {
        didSet { next?.previous = self }
    }
    
    init(_ value: Data) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Comment: this exactly what I was about to propose :) Btw I just named the generic type Value instead of Data `protocol LinkedProtocol {
    associatedtype Value
    var value: Value { get }
    var next: Self? { get }
}`

Answer (score 3):

Swift's subclasses don't allow properties to be covariently override (that is, to have a type that is a subtype of the `super`'s type for that property).

Here's a simpler example, without the generics:

```
class Animal {}
class Bird: Animal {}

class AnimalFeeder {
    var animalToFeed: Animal
    
    init() { fatalError("not relevant to the example") }
}

class BirdFeeder: AnimalFeeder {
    override var animalToFeed: Bird // error: cannot override mutable property 'animalToFeed' of type 'Animal' with covariant type 'Bird'
}
```

You have pretty much the sample example, except `Self` is playing both the animal and the animal feeder roles from this analogy.

#### This data model is fundamentally broken

It suffers from the [square-rectangle problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/238176/109689). Unless the `next` and `prev` pointers are tightly encapsulated, and exposed only through controlled functions, then this class breaks the LSP.

If you were to pass a `DoublyNode<T>` to an algorithm that expects a `LinkedNode<T>` that algorithm can operate upon the structure of the linked list, only treating as singly-linked, and ignoring the `prev` references. In doing so, it's fundamentally broken the invariant of the doubly-linked list, and made it invalid.

The `didSet` observer helps, but it doesn't fire upon initialization (so the object can be wrong from the start). I think this is all fixable by adding more encapsulation, and making this objects more authoritative over their properties, so that they can ensure that they stay valid. But I think that's a moot point, because there's a deeper issue:

"These two classes share 2 out of 3 fields" isn't a good motivation for inheritance. And really, what else do you gain from this inheritance? I think you would get much more value from having two seperate linked node classes, each owned by a `struct SinglyLinkedList<T>` and a `struct DoublyLinkedList<T>`, which conform to `Collection` and `BidirectionalCollection` respectively (which defines forward and backward iteration)